# Distribution of a poisson process in an exponential random variable

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I think I already solve this problem but I would like to know your opinion about the solution.

Let $\{X(t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ be a poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, and T an exponential random variable with parameter $\alpha$ find the distribution of $X(T)$

My solution:
First of all I apply Law of total probability over all posible values of T:

$$P(X(T)=x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X(T)=x \mid T=t) f_T(t) dt $$

Where $f_T(t)$ is the density function of $T$

That integral becomes:
$$P(X(T)=x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t)^x}{x!} \alpha e^{-\alpha t}  dt $$
$$P(X(T)=x)= \frac{\alpha \lambda^x}{x!} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\lambda+ \alpha) t} t^x dt $$

And the integral is a gamma function (doing a change of variable)

Then the result would be:

$$ P(X(T)=x)= \frac{\alpha \lambda^x }{x!} \frac{1}{(\alpha + \lambda)^{x+1}} \Gamma(x+1)$$

What do you think about this solution?

Comment: Looks right . You should however mention that the exponential RV $T$ needs to be independent of $X$.

Comment: Oh yeah! sure! I forgot that, but  that assumption is in the problem. Thank you!